# Laptop keyboard wont work after bios boot process

Tags: laptop, keyboard, bios

I have a strange problem in a ASUS Laptop: after bios screen, the keyboard just stop working. No FN Keys or other keys works.

I have replaced the keyboard to a new one from the manufacter, but it wont work either.
After that, I noticed that when I boot the machine, I can access bios (by entering F2 key) - thats very strange. I think bios boot process cause a problem?

Also, just to be sure, I have updated Bios Version and it did not work either.

PS. USB keyboards and touchpad work fine.

Someone has encountered a similar problem or knows the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To recap:

- The computer is clearly reading the keyboard correctly (because you can use it to access the BIOS)
- The keyboard isn't working once you've made it to the OS
- Other similar hardware is working in the OS

Have you checked this keyboard's status in device manager? (I've made the assumption you're on Windows). It could be that the keyboard, as an individual device, is disabled or has broken drivers.

Comment: The problem is not on the OS, as I have tried linux, windows and also in the installation process it didn't work.